# Real-time audio visualization in an Angular application

Tags: angular

Creating Real-time Audio Visualization in Angular

I'm looking to implement a real-time audio visualization in an Angular application, similar to the three vertical lines that react to audio in Google Meet. These lines should move up and down in sync with the audio. Can anyone provide guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this in Angular?

I want exactly something like this: https://mdn.github.io/voice-change-o-matic/

Comment: I have written a vue.js component for this, you might want to look there to get some ideas: https://github.com/suterma/vue-audio-level-meter/blob/main/src/components/AudioLevelMeter.vue The trick is to use an audio analyzer node from the HTML Web Audio API